# V-data-table selection checkboxes initially on, using custom row template

Tags: vue.js, templates, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I'm using a custom template for each row in a v-data-table and I am trying to have checkboxes working for each row. For some reason if i use :value="item" all checkboxes are initially checked. I am not sure how it should be done. I want them not-to-be checked initially... When selecting, complete item should be added to `selected`. Also, on `v-data-table` I have `show-select` and this (de)select all checkbox must work. This is the case but initially I now have to use it before the checkboxes for the rows actually work.

```
<template #item="{ item }">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <v-checkbox v-model="selected" :value="item"></v-checkbox>
            </td>
            <td v-for="field in fields" v-bind:key="field.id">{{ item[field.value] }}
            </td>
```

Comment: I already tried :input-value without success

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve that without creating a separate template for the checkboxes.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      singleSelect: false,
      selected: [],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.30/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.30/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <h5>Selected: {{selected}}</h5>
    <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      show-select
      class="elevation-1"
    >
     
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

***Updated :*** Below is the demo based on the custom template as per the author demand.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      singleSelect: false,
      selected: [],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.30/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.30/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <h5>Selected: {{selected}}</h5>
    <v-data-table
                  v-model="selected"
                  :headers="headers"
                  :items="desserts"
                  item-key="name"
                  show-select
                  class="elevation-1"
                  >
      <template v-slot:items="item">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <v-checkbox v-model="selected" :value="item"></v-checkbox>
          </td>
          <td v-for="field in Object.keys(item)" v-bind:key="item[field]">{{ item[field] }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: But as soon as you actually use custom templates for the whole row, the checkboxes disappear as well :(

Comment: @Niels I updated the answer as per your requirement. Please have a look. Hope it will work as per your expectation now :)

Comment: props.item does not seem to work. it says: Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: What i don't understand is when i just replace {item} with {props} and change item to props everywhere it used, it also does not work anymore. It says props is undefined

Comment: @Niels I updated the 2nd code snippet as per your changes. If you directly want to access item. Then `v-slot` should be defined as `v-slot:items="item"`.

Comment: it should be item, not items, and it works the same

Comment: using 'items' there just de-activates the custom template entirely, that's why it works

Comment: @Niels You can modify it as per your requirement. I just spent some time so that I can give you an idea how to go. Please feel free to accept this as a answer if it helps you. So that it will help other developers as well.